# "invalid sequence of tokens near ['for']" error in painless script query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am getting error while executing this script query using Nest library in .net:

```
new ScriptQuery
                                        {
                                            Lang = "painless",
                                            Source = "(!doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].empty && doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude) * 0.000621371 <= params.maxDistance) || (!doc[params.offices].empty && (for (def office : doc[params.offices].values){if(office.coordinates).arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude) * 0.000621371 < =params.maxDistance{return true;}}))",
                                            Params = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                            {
                                                {"headquartersCoordinatesField", Field<Provider>(f => f.Headquarters.Coordinates)},
                                                {"offices", Field<Provider>(f => f.Offices)},
                                                {"latitude", _latitude},
                                                {"longitude", _longitude},
                                                {"maxDistance", 50} 
                                            }
                                        }
```

This is the error I get :
ServerError: Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed" CausedBy: "Type: script_exception Reason: "compile error" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "invalid sequence of tokens near ['for']." CausedBy: "Type: no_viable_alt_exception Reason: "no_viable_alt_exception: null""""

I also tried boolean variable inside loop and try to return that at the end but I get the same error.

I tried simple for loop with counter (i) to check the syntax but same error. So it seems like anything I use inside loop is returning error.

Can someone help to find the correct syntax ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `for` loop inside a condition, it doesn't make sense.

Here is how your script should look like:

```
def hqCoordExist = !doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].empty;
def distToHq = doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude);
if (hqCoordExist && distToHq * 0.000621371 <= params.maxDistance) {
  return true;
}
 
def officesExist = !doc[params.offices].empty;
if (officesExist) {
  for (def office : doc[params.offices].values) {
    def distToOffice = office.coordinates.arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude);
    if (distToOffice * 0.000621371 <= params.maxDistance) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I tried to run this script ( second part) and I get this general error without much details. First part runs without error. :   "error": "Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /qa1-provider-search/doc/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: \"all shards failed\""

Comment: I am using elastic version 6.7. Does that make any difference ?

Comment: Can you share the full error you see in the ES server logs please?

Comment: I am not sure how would I get the ES server logs. Also I don't have full access to it. But with minor changes to your script, this is the error I see :"error": "Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /qa1-provider-search/doc/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: \"all shards failed\" CausedBy: \"Type: script_exception Reason: \"compile error\" CausedBy: \"Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: \"Extraneous for loop.\"\"

Comment: we have AWS managed elastic instance , just in case, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had to check key and size of offices param. :

```
if(!doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].empty && doc[params.headquartersCoordinatesField].arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude) * 0.000621371 <= params.maxDistance) 
{ 
  return true; 
} 
def officesCollection = new ArrayList();
if(doc.containsKey(params.offices) && doc[params.offices].size() > 0) 
{ 
 officesCollection = doc[params.offices].value; 
 for (def office : officesCollection)
 {
  def distToOffice = 
  office.coordinates.arcDistance(params.latitude, params.longitude);
  if (distToOffice * 0.000621371 <= params.maxDistance)
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).